# Scipy Optimize unable to optimize even with strong starting parameters

Tags: optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a fairly simple function that I would like to optimize the parameters for but I cannot get `scipy.optimize.minimize` to succeed.

Here's a simplified version of the data and the problem:

```
ref = np.array([0.586, 0.659, 0.73 , 0.799, 0.865, 0.929, 0.991, 1.05 , 1.107, 1.162])

input = np.array([70.0, 77.0, 82.0, 87.0, 93.0, 98.0, 98.0, 102.0, 106.0, 109.0])

x = np.array([6.96,  9.24, 10.92, 12.24, 13.92, 15.24, 15.24, 16.32, 17.64, 18.96])

## Function 
def fun(beta, x):
    return ((input**beta[0])*beta[2])*(x**beta[1])

## Starting parameters 
initial_guess = [0.15, 0.9475, 0.0427]

## Objective to be minimized 
def objective(beta, model, x, ref):
    return sum(((np.log(model(beta, x))-np.log(ref)))**2)

minimize(objective, initial_guess, args = (fun, x, ref))
```

I know that these starting parameters are almost correct as `print(fun(initial_guess, x))` returns estimates close to the reference data (and they're much closer in my real situation than in this minimal reproducible example).

I've tried many combinations of starting parameters and cannot find any that lead to successful optimization.

I've tried making the function more basic (e.g., removing the additional `beta` terms and `x`, leaving only `beta[0]`). This successfully optimizes (`success: True`) however the predictions are inadequate (presumably because the function is not complex enough to convert the input a desirable output with respect to the reference).

I've minimized functions apparently more complex than this in recent times (and used the same approach in this instance as in previous ones), so I am confused as to why this one is not working.

Comment: This being a reproducible example is somewhat dubious. The data look fairly linear and so either your real data are extremely different, or your log step is quite unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, the real data are not real linear but more Gompertz shaped.

Answer (score 1):

`minimize` is not the right function call. Use `curve_fit`, and it works fine even without your log step. Further, always give `minimize` (or `curve_fit`) sane bounds; if you've "used the same approach" and it worked without bounds in the past that's only by coincidence.

In one sense this is really a surface fit over three dimensions, and interpreted as such it doesn't have enough input data. I would expect multiple non-monotonic jumps in one of `x` or `input` for such a scheme. What this *should* look like (with different values in `ix`):

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def fun(ix: np.ndarray, b0: float, b1: float, b2: float) -> np.ndarray:
    input_, x = ix
    return input_**b0 * b2 * x**b1


ref = np.array([0.586, 0.659, 0.73, 0.799, 0.865, 0.929, 0.991, 1.05, 1.107, 1.162])
ix = np.array((
    [70.0, 77.0, 82.0, 87.0, 93.0, 98.0, 98.0, 102.0, 106.0, 109.0],
    [6.96, 9.24, 10.92, 12.24, 13.92, 15.24, 15.24, 16.32, 17.64, 18.96],
))
initial_guess = (2, -0.5, 4e-4)
fit_param, _ = curve_fit(
    f=fun, xdata=ix, ydata=ref, p0=initial_guess,
    bounds=((-1,-1,0), (10, 10, 10)),
)
print(fit_param)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ix[0], ref, label='experiment')
ax.plot(ix[0], fun(ix, *initial_guess), label='guess')
ax.plot(ix[0], fun(ix, *fit_param), label='fit')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: guess and fit]

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks for that. Why doesn't `minimize` work in this scenario?

Comment: It's not appropriate, you aren't giving the optimization package much to work with - only a scalar, whereas with `curve_fit` you give it a full vector